# Route Incoming Twilio Call to another Browser Client

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-click-to-call

An agent needs to route the active call to another agent.

I got one article to do with `Node.js` [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/change-call-state). But, not sure what to do with `Javascript client`.

Can I modify an existing connection? Following is my code for accepting incoming calls.

```
Twilio.Device.setup(window.twilioToken);

// Handle incoming calls from Twilio
Twilio.Device.incoming(function (conn) {
    conn.accept();
});
```

Now, one call is active on the browser. Is there any method to update the client based on Client SID?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

If you have multiple agents that you need to answer incoming calls using [Twilio Client](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client) then you might want to take a look at [Twilio TaskRouter](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/taskrouter).

TaskRouter is perfect for distributing calls to call center agents. It allows you to setup workers and workflows and turn incoming calls into tasks that are delivered to available workers. Check out the [quickstart guide to TaskRouter](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart?filter-product=taskrouter) and [how to build a multi-channel support desk using TaskRouter](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/02/multi-channel-support-desk-taskrouter.html).